# Create a function that accepts two different objects that have the same method

Tags: go

I'm learning Golang and want to understand the "Go way" of solving this problem.

Specifically, I'm using the `sql` package and I'm seeing some redundant functionality in my code that I'd like to pull out into a function.

### My Original Code

I have, ***1)*** a user struct:

```
type User struct {
  ID        int
  FirstName string
  LastName  string
}
```

***2)*** a function for getting one user by ID from the database (Postgresql):

```
func GetUserById(id int) (user User) {
  sql := `
    SELECT id, first_name, last_name
    FROM users
    WHERE id = $1
  `
  row := db.QueryRow(sql, id)
  err := row.Scan(&user.ID, &user.FirstName, &user.LastName)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  return
}
```

and, ***3)*** a function for getting all users from the database:

```
func GetUsers() (users []User) {
  sql := `
    SELECT id, first_name, last_name
    FROM users
    ORDER BY last_name
  `
  rows, err := db.Query(sql)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  for rows.Next() {
    user := User{}
    err := rows.Scan(&user.ID, &user.FirstName, &user.LastName)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    users = append(users, user)
  }
  rows.Close()
  return
}
```

### Desired Refactor

With only 3 fields in the user record, this is a trivial example.  But, with a few more fields, the `rows.Scan(...)` piece of both data access functions would be nice to move to a function that both could call:

```
func ScanUserFromRow(row *sql.Row) (user User) {
  err := row.Scan(&user.ID, &user.FirstName, &user.LastName)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  return
}
```

Then the updated database access functions would look something like:

```
func GetUserById(id int) (user User) {
  sql := `
    SELECT id, first_name, last_name
    FROM users
    WHERE id = $1
  `
  row := db.QueryRow(sql, id)
  user = ScanUserFromRow(row)
  return
}

func GetUsers() (users []User) {
  sql := `
    SELECT id, first_name, last_name
    FROM users
    ORDER BY last_name
  `
  rows, err := db.Query(sql)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  for rows.Next() {
    user := ScanUserFromRow(rows)
    users = append(users, user)
  }
  rows.Close()
  return
}
```

However, in the case of the `GetUserById` function, I'm dealing with an `*sql.Row` struct pointer.  In the case of the `GetUsers` function, I'm dealing with an `*sql.Rows` struct pointer.  The two are different... obviously, but *similar* in that they both have a `Scan` method.

It seems the type system won't let me create a method that will accept one or the other.  Is there a way to do this utilizing `interface{}`, or is there some other more idiomatic Go solution for this?

### Update/Solution

With this question, I'm saying both `sql.Row` and `sql.Rows` are ducks that "quack" with `Scan`.  How can I use a function argument that allows both?

[@seh provided an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37504976/2325596) that allows the sort of duck-typing I was hoping for by making the argument a custom interface.  Here is the resulting code:

```
type rowScanner interface {
  Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
}

func ScanPlayerFromRow(rs rowScanner) (u User) {
  err := rs.Scan(&u.ID, &u.FirstName, &u.LastName)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  return
}
```

[**...or,** as @Kaveh pointed out below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511481/2325596), the definition of the interface can be inlined in the function argument:

```
func ScanPlayerFromRow(rs interface {
  Scan(des ...interface{}) error
}) (u User) {
  err := rs.Scan(&u.ID, &u.FirstName, &u.LastName)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  return
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [`sql.Rows`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows) and [`sql.Row`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Row) have [a `Scan` method](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Row.Scan). There's no interface containing that method in the standard library, but it's possible to define it yourself:

```
type rowScanner interface {
    Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
}
```

You can then write a function that operates on a `rowScanner` rather than a `*sql.Row` or a `*sql.Rows`:

```
 import "database/sql"

 type rowScanner interface {
    Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
 }

 func handleRow(scanner rowScanner) error {
    var i int
    return scanner.Scan(&i)
 }

 func main() {
    var row *sql.Row
    handleRow(row) // Crashes due to calling on a nil pointer.
    var rows *sql.Rows
    handleRow(rows)  // Crashes due to calling on a nil pointer.
 }
```

I didn't mock up using a real `*sql.Row` or `*sql.Rows`, but that should give you the idea. Your desired `ScanUserFromRow` function would demand a `rowScanner` instead of `*sql.Row`.

Comment: Thank you, @seh.  This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Note too that Kaveh shows an alternate approach below: eliminate the `rowScanner` interface as a named type, and inline the interface definition in the function parameter. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37511481/31818

Answer (score 2):

In this case I'd refactor both to `Query()` with `sql.rows` and have both return `users[]`. Then add a convenience function to return the first item in that array if we know ids are unique.

Something like:

```
type User struct {
  ID        int
  FirstName string
  LastName  string
}
```

```
func GetUser(id int) (user User) {
  users := getUsers(id)
  if (len(users) > 0) {
      user = users[0]
  }
  return
}
```

```
func GetUsers() []User {
  return getUsers(0)
}
```

```
func getUsers(id int) (users []User) {
  rows := getUserRows(id)
  for rows.Next() {
    user := User{}
    err := rows.Scan(&user.ID, &user.FirstName, &user.LastName)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    users = append(users, user)
  }
  if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }
  rows.Close()
  return
}

func getUserRows(id int) (rows sql.Rows) {
  sqlSelect := `
    SELECT id, first_name, last_name
    FROM users`
  sqlWhere := `
    WHERE id = $1`
  sqlOrder := `
    ORDER BY last_name`
  var err error
  if (0 == id) {
    rows, err = db.Query(sqlSelect + sqlOrder)
  } else {
    rows, err = db.Query(sqlSelect + sqlWhere + sqlOrder, id)
  }
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  return
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  I definitely think this is a reasonable refactor, removing the other piece of duplication in my code, the SQL query.  However, this also removes the need for the code that was at the heart of my question (i.e. how to generalize a function argument, so that it can accept more than one specific type).

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce the argument of your function to obey a specific interface - in this case, having a `Scan(dest ...interface{}) error` method:

```
func sampleHandler(ru interface {
    Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
}) error {
    var data []interface{}
    // result of some action in your logic
    return ru.Scan(data)
}
```

Comment: I like this approach too.  It's a bit less readable than the approach of defining the custom interface, but it alleviates the need to come up with a name for the interface, which I think has a hidden benefit.  If you name the interface, you assign meaning to it, which you have to reason about.  That may lead to some wasted mental effort since the meaning/name of this interface isn't all that important.

Comment: Exactly! As always; it depends!